# Pass data from tableview to view controller in tab bar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Im fairly new to Xcode and seems to be having a bit of a problem. I was passing data from my tableviewcontroller to EventViewController and it worked fine with the code bellow:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if let destination = segue.destination as? EventViewController {
    destination.Event = events[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
  }
}
```

But I needed to make some changes to the app and Embedded a tab bar controller to the EventViewController, and now I can't get it to run. How do I pass data to the First tab in the Tabbarcontroller instead? :) Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = (segue.destination as? UITabBarController)?.viewControllers.first as? EventViewController {

        destination.event = events[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]

    }
}
```